# What's the difference between Netty ChannelHandler's exceptionCaught and channelInactive

Tags: netty

I'm learnning Netty and got confused by ChannelHandler's channelInactive and exceptionCaught.

From what I've learned, when the Server is down, the Client will get an IOEException, but if the Server close the Channel explicitly, the client will get a WRITE_IDEL event and it can define post-processing itself.

But from the demo bellow, I got different result. I shut the Server down, the Client jumper to channelInactive method but not exceptionCaught.

ClientHandler：

```
package echoclient;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleState;
import io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateEvent;
import io.netty.util.CharsetUtil;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by lulijun on 2018/2/12.
 */
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class EchoClientHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {



    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {

        System.out.println("channel active");
    }


    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("channel inactive");
    }


    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf in) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Client received: "+in.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));


    }

    @Override
    public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
        if (evt instanceof IdleStateEvent) {
            IdleState state= ((IdleStateEvent) evt).state();
            if (state == IdleState.WRITER_IDLE) {
                // read timeout, break the channel
                System.out.println("client write timeout");
                SocketAddress remoteAddress = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();

            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {


        System.out.println("channel exception");
        cause.printStackTrace();

        if (cause instanceof IOException) {

            SocketAddress remoteAddress = ctx.channel().remoteAddress();

           // reconnect
            ctx.channel().close();
            ctx.connect(remoteAddress);
        } else {
            ctx.channel().close();
        }

    }


    protected void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Client received: "+msg.toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The channelInActive method is execute when the channel is closed hence also the connection is closed.

Any exceptions that are thrown by inbound handlers will propagate "up" the pipeline and invoke this handler's exceptionCaught() method, assuming a handler below does not consume them.